# How to perform select on multiple colums where value of second column could be any value

Tags: mysql, select, multiple-columns, wildcard

I have a simple MySQL database with columns for location (let's say values texas, Colorado and Virginia) and zone (let's say values internal, external, and private).

I'm trying to develop a PHP web form that will let me display devices based on a selection of values from both columns where one possible option is "ALL".  How do I structure a query such that location is a specific value (let's say Texas), but the zone is all values.  In English:  Show me devices in texas in all zones.

There doesn't appear to be a "*" to match any value, and no regex pattern matches all values in the zone column.  I'm sending the query through a simple PHP form, so simply omitting zone as a parameter for the SELECT is not an option because the query is static in the PHP code and needs to allow for a specific value (i.e. internal),   So what value can I pass from the form that will represent ANY zone.

I've tried a plethora or SELECT queries, but none seem to work with a web form that allows submitting either specific values or "ALL"

```
SELECT * FROM device WHERE location LIKE 'texas' AND sw_zone IN (????);
```

I expect the output to be

```
| texas | internal |

| texas | external |

| texas | private  |
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two paths you can take here. One is to modify the query, and the other is the write a little more PHP code.

If you decide you want to modify the query, one option would be to use a sub query to first select all zones. Your query would be similar to this if "all" is selected:

```
SELECT * FROM device WHERE location Like 'texas' AND sw_zone IN (SELECT DISTINCT sw_zone FROM device WHERE sw_zone LIKE 'internal')
```

Internal is the only value you have to change with this query, and it should support wildcards. Ex:

```
SELECT * FROM device WHERE location Like 'texas' AND sw_zone IN (SELECT DISTINCT sw_zone FROM device WHERE sw_zone LIKE '%')
```